# Build Error OpenWRT hotplug2

Tags: openwrt

i have a problem while building openWRT for the carambola module. The package hotplug2 is the problem.

```
make[2]: Entering directory /carambola/package/hotplug2
mkdir -p /carambola/dl
echo "Checking out files from the svn repository..."; mkdir -p /carambola/tmp/dl && cd /carambola/tmp/dl && rm -rf hotplug2-201 && [ \! -d hotplug2-201 ] && ( svn help export | grep -q trust-server-cert && svn export --non-interactive --trust-server-cert -r201 http://svn.nomi.cz/svn/isteve/hotplug2 hotplug2-201 || svn export --non-interactive -r201 http://svn.nomi.cz/svn/isteve/hotplug2 hotplug2-201 ) && echo "Packing checkout..." &&   /bin/tar cfz //carambola/tmp/dl/hotplug2-201.tar.gz hotplug2-201 && mv /home/hosst/Dokumente/Projekte/OSC_GIT/02_WSS/linux-system/carambola/tmp/dl/hotplug2-201.tar.gz /carambola/dl/ && rm -rf hotplug2-201; 
Checking out files from the svn repository...
svn: E670002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://svn.nomi.cz/svn/isteve/hotplug2'
svn: E670002: Name or service not known
svn: E670002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://svn.nomi.cz/svn/isteve/hotplug2'
svn: E670002: Name or service not known
make[2]: *** [/carambola/dl/hotplug2-201.tar.gz] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory /carambola/package/hotplug2
make[1]: *** [package/hotplug2/compile] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory carambola
make: *** [package/hotplug2/compile] Fehler 2
```

Obviously the svn repo http://svn.nomi.cz/svn/isteve/hotplug2 is not reachable. But this is the original makefile from OpenWRT Repo (hotplug2 package).

Does anybody know the problem? Could not find any hints on the net but i am sure many other people can compile OpenWRT without problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the url of svn repo has changed. Make these changes in

**package/hotplug2/Makefile**

```
#PKG_REV:=201
PKG_REV:=4 

#PKG_SOURCE_URL:=http://svn.nomi.cz/svn/isteve/hotplug2
PKG_SOURCE_URL:=http://hotplug2.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
```

With those changes, you should be able to compile the code.